# Prove that the series is convergent and calculate the sum.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let's say  that $$x_{1} \gt 0$$  We define the sequence by the formula
>   $$x_{n+1} = - \ln(x_{1} +x_{2}+x_{3}+\dots+x_{n}) $$
>   Prove that the series $$\sum_{n=2}^{ \infty } x_{n}$$ is convergent and find the sum of it.

My attempt was to use the identity $$\ln(1+x)\lt x$$ somehow, but without any results.  I've also determined that the elements of the sequence are positive and that $$x_{n+1} = - \ln(x_{1} +x_{2}+x_{3}+\dots+x_{n}) = \ln\left(\frac{1}{x_{1} +x_{2}+x_{3}+\dots+x_{n}}\right)$$

Comment: So we have $x_{n+1}=-\ln(x_1-\ln x_1-\ln(x_1-\ln x_1)-\ln(x_1-\ln x_1-\ln(x_1-\ln x_1))-\dots$

Comment: The elements of the sequence are not necessarily positive, unless $0\le x_1\lt 1$.  If $x_1\gt1$, then $x_2=-\ln(x_1)$ is negative.

Comment: One simple observation: If the series converges, then $x_n\to0$. It follows from the assumed identity that the sum of the series is $e^0=1$.

Answer (score 8):

Let $s_n=\sum _{k=1}^n x_k$ for $n\geq 1$. Then $s_{n+1}=s_n-\log(s_n)$.  So it comes down to showing that iterating $x\mapsto x-\log(x)$ converges when you start with some positive $x$.  Now use that $x-\log(x) \geq 1$ with equality only for $x=1$ and that $1<x-\log(x)<x$ for $x>1$.

Comment: Ah, of course! You nailed it.

Comment: In this case, the partial sum is more than the sum of its parts...

Comment: Immeasurable comment.

Answer (score 1):

We have $e^{-x_{n+1}} = x_1+...+x_n \ge 1-x_{n+1}$. Hence
$x_1+...+x_n + x_{n+1} \ge 1$, and consequently, $x_{n+1} \le 0$ for all $n>1$.

Hence the sequence $x_1+...+x_{n+1}$ is non-increasing and bounded below, so it converges. Since it converges, $x_n \to 0$, from which it follows that $x_1+...+x_n = e^{-x_{n+1}} \to 1$.

Comment: To atone for my earlier contractive sins...